# Filtering a MongoDb collection with geo functions and loading into Spark

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-spark, geolocation

I am attempting to run some clustering algorithms (Bisecting K-Means, HDBSCAN etc) on a subset of a MongoDb collection.
The documents in the collection contain geo-coordinates (stored as both a GeoJsonPoint and as separate lat/lon)
e.g.:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce59"
  },
  "lat": 51.1315842777413,
  "lon": 0.515861112040389,
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0.515861112040389,
      51.1315842777413
    ]
  },
  "lastUpdatedTimestamp": {
    "$numberLong": "1683902535038"
  },
  "_class": "com.example.DataPoint"
}
```

I need to be able to filter the documents based on 2 sets of criteria:

1. Location is inside a predefined GeoJsonPolygon (these are stored in another collection elsewhere)
2. LastUpdatedTimestamp > than a fixed time

and then read the filtered collection into Spark to perform the clustering.

The application is being developed in Springboot Java, so I am able to setup a mongo respository with methods than will perform this filtering (which use Mongo's inbuilt geometry functions)

DataPointRepository class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPolygon;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DataPointRepository extends MongoRepository<DataPoint, ObjectId> {
    
    //Extract by within GeoPolygon And Last updated > cutoff 
    List<DataPoint> findAllByLocationWithinAndLastUpdatedTimestampGreaterThan(GeoJsonPolygon geoJsonPolygon, double lastUpdatedCutoff);

}
```

DataPoint class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPolygon;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.GeoSpatialIndexType;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.GeoSpatialIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@Document(collection ="DataPoint") 
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DataPoint {
    
    //System generated PK
    @Getter @Setter @NonNull private String id;
    
    //Co-ordinates
    @Getter @Setter private double lat;
    @Getter @Setter private double lon;
    
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(name= "location_idx", type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    @Getter @Setter private GeoJsonPoint location;
    
    //Last Updated
    @Getter @Setter private long lastUpdatedTimestamp;  
}
```

The below service will then run when the application is initialised and performs the collection filtering and loading of the data into spark:

```
package com.example;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPolygon;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Service
public class ExampleService implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleService.class);

    @Autowired
    DataPointRepository dataPointRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //Log that service is running
        logger.info("Example Service is running");
        
        //Example GeoJsonPolygon
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        points.add(new Point(0,0));
        points.add(new Point(180,0));
        points.add(new Point(180,90));
        points.add(new Point(0,0));
        GeoJsonPolygon geoJsonPolygon = new GeoJsonPolygon(points);
        
        //Cutoff time default to T-10mins
        double cutoffTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (10 * 60 * 1000);
        
        //Filter the DataPoint collection
        List<DataPoint> filteredDataPointList = dataPointRepository.findAllByLocationWithinAndLastUpdatedTimestampGreaterThan(geoJsonPolygon,cutoffTime);
        
        //Initialise Spark session
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        
        conf.set("spark.master","local");
        conf.set("spark.app.name","ExampleApp");

        SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(context).getOrCreate();
        
        //Convert filteredDataPointList to List<Row> for spark dataframe
        List<Row> rowList = new ArrayList<Row>();
        for (DataPoint dp: filteredDataPointList) {
            List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(dp.getId());
            data.add(dp.getLat());
            data.add(dp.getLon());
            
            Row row = RowFactory.create(data.toArray());
            rowList.add(row);
        }
        
        //Generate schema from StructFields
        List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<>();
        structFields.add(new StructField("_id", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()));
        structFields.add(new StructField("lat", DataTypes.DoubleType, true, Metadata.empty()));
        structFields.add(new StructField("lon", DataTypes.DoubleType, true, Metadata.empty()));
        StructType schema = new StructType(structFields.toArray(new StructField[0]));

        //Initialise DataFrame from rowList
        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.createDataFrame(rowList, schema);
        dataset.withColumn("lat", dataset.col("lat").cast("float"));
        dataset.withColumn("lon", dataset.col("lon").cast("float"));
        dataset.na().drop();
        dataset.printSchema();
        dataset.show(false);
        
        //Run clustering algorithms....
        
    }
}
```

(output as below)

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: double (nullable = true)

+------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|_id                     |lat             |lon               |
+------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce59|51.1315842777413|0.515861112040389 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5a|53.7236662883316|-3.03878489019157 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5b|53.025813155572 |0.289110683451985 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5c|51.3606995421023|-0.45591666788182 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5d|55.3587772650236|-0.43234332482597 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5e|53.3132727039887|-1.2439138924336  |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce5f|55.5844946099286|-2.71052395578811 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce60|52.3681859288013|-1.73289160535643 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce61|53.6486857624155|0.879253900600117 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce62|51.8974330698587|-1.64057831174821 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce63|51.4130112162052|0.0813730046672143|
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce64|55.7826244597159|-1.89958309132911 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce65|51.9251715855348|-2.50507999470767 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce66|52.2918854778935|-1.97167759407929 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce67|54.8403636027267|-1.36478903883441 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce68|52.6971321174423|-0.111767454525473|
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce69|53.0566617126824|-0.15553981089494 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce6a|52.8988372634014|-1.41853339786962 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce6b|55.717825981325 |0.211642792759744 |
|6453b52f26d1a71e6124ce6c|52.3840761519566|-0.653960353317823|
+------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

However, I would like to load the data from the collection directly into spark without having to read the extracted documents into a list and iterate through in java to perform the dataframe conversion.
Currently though, I am only able to read in the entire collection if I read directly into spark:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    
conf.set("spark.master","local");
conf.set("spark.app.name","ExampleApp");
    
conf.set("spark.jars.packages","org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.1");

// Set up read connection :
conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://user:password@example.com:27017");
conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.database", "ExampleDb");
conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.collection", "DataPoint");

// Set up write connection
conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://user:password@example.com:27017");
conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.database", "ExampleDb");
conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.collection", "DataPoint");

SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(context).getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("mongodb").load().select(col("_id"), col("lat"), col("lon"));
dataset.withColumn("lat", dataset.col("lat").cast("float"));
dataset.withColumn("lon", dataset.col("lon").cast("float"));
dataset.na().drop();
dataset.printSchema();
dataset.show(false);
```

My questions are:

What is the most efficient way of reading the desired data into Spark? Should the entire collection be loaded, the repository methods above scrapped, and Spark's functions used to perform the filtering instead, or is there a away to apply mongo's geo functions to the read?
If the former, is there an efficient way to compare lat/lon doubles to a predefined geo polygon and only keep rows in the dataframe where the coordinates lie inside?

Or, if is still better to keep the repository methods above, is there a more efficient way to convert the list into a dataframe?

If the answer depends on the volume of data, then I'd certainly want to entertain both approaches and run performance tests myself.